# ConEmu: Issues starting PowerShell

Tags: powershell, conemu

I can't get the PowerShell started from a ConEmu console.

Trying to start with `powershell.exe -NoProfile` (works from cmd.exe). When I start it as a task I get:

> ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=0.
>   Press Enter or Esc to close console...

Even if I start a cmd.exe console in ConEmu and execute `powershell.exe -NoProfile` nothing happens. Tried with `cmd.exe /k powershell.exe -NoProfile`. No way to get the PowerShell console.
Any hints to debug this strange behaviour?

Comment: Windows and ConEmu versions?

Comment: `powershell.exe -NoProfile -NoExit`?

Comment: -NoExit doesn't work

Comment: The problem is it does not work anymore _out of the blue_. Of course there is no 'out of the blue' with software. My laptop works from a different network location now. I added '-NoProfile' to exclude any effects of initialization. Worked so far for Win10 and ConEmu 180415

Comment: There might be a connection to **WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)**. I installed this this on my laptop. Unfortunately, turning this feature of doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having this same problem at about the same time you did and I couldn't figure it out  even after I upgraded to newer versions of [CONEMU 180617](https://conemu.github.io/blog/2018/06/17/Build-180617.html). I also don't have Admin rights on my work computer and I really wanted my CONEMU setup back for Powershell. Well I finally got it working and I hope this will help you as well. I am able to run Powershell on my Windows 10 machine now!

Create a new task and then use this syntax:

`powershell.exe -cur_console:c1:f:i:n`

From the [ConEmu Docs](https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html#syntax)

- cur_console[:switches]

  - c - force enable ‘Press Enter or Esc to close console’ confirmation

    - c0 - wait for Enter/Esc silently
    - c1 - don't close console automatically, even by Enter/Esc
  - f - force starting console active, useful when starting several consoles simultaneously
  - i - don't inject ConEmuHk into starting process
  - n - disable ‘Press Enter or Esc to close console’

Comment: I'm so glad its working for you! Can you mark my answer as useful?